# Python can't inport pydicom: ImportError: No module named dicom

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, pydicom

I am new Ubuntu and Python, so any help will be appreciated.

I need to write Python program that works with dicom images. (MRI data)

I installed pydicom with:

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/auto pydicom
```

(after trying pip install and comda install)
in conda list I sea:
"pydicom                   *  0.9.8                    py27_0  auto "

When running: `import dicom`
in Jupyter notebook, I get:

```
ImportError: No module named dicom
```

( I tried "import pydicom as dicom" same error)

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
conda 4.0.6
Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
Jupyter version: 4.1.0

I suspect that I have some problem with environment variables,
when i try to run ipython notebook, I get:

```
ImportError: No module named backports.shutil_get_terminal_size
```

but jupyter notebook, is working.

When I run: `locate -i dicom`
I see dicom in spyder directories only:

/home/naomi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderplugins/io_dicom.py
/home/naomi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderplugins/io_dicom.pyc
/home/naomi/anaconda/pkgs/spyder-2.3.5.2-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderplugins/io_dicom.py
/home/naomi/anaconda/pkgs/spyder-2.3.5.2-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderplugins/io_dicom.pyc
/home/naomi/anaconda/pkgs/spyder-2.3.8-py27_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderplugins/io_dicom.py
/home/naomi/anaconda/pkgs/spyder-2.3.8-py27_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderplugins/io_dicom.pyc

When I run: `locate -i pydicom`
I don't get any directory.
Is it installed ?

Comment: I found the dicom package in: /anaconda/pkgs/pydicom-0.9.8-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dicom/ so its probably installed and its only issue of environment variable of some sort.

Comment: conda search pydicom                                                            pydicom                   *  0.9.8                    py27_0  auto                                                                                                                 conda install pydicom                                                                                                             # All requested packages already installed